# Elastic beanstalk not using reserved instance

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-sdk

I'm trying to figure out why my reserved instance is *not* being used.  I was deploying with `region: us-east-1` and it was not utilizing my available reserved instance that is in `us-east-1c`.  Amazon billing tells me to pay for premium support, even though I have presented the evidence that the `aws-sdk-core` rejects the `us-east-1c` subregion:

```
Seahorse::Client::NetworkingError: unable to connect to `elasticbeanstalk.us-east-1c.amazonaws.com`; SocketError: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
/Users/kross/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@acme/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.1.26/lib/seahorse/client/net_http/connection_pool.rb:292:in `start_session'
/Users/kross/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@acme/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.1.26/lib/seahorse/client/net_http/connection_pool.rb:104:in `session_for'
/Users/kross/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@acme/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.1.26/lib/seahorse/client/net_http/handler.rb:108:in `session'
/Users/kross/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@acme/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.1.26/lib/seahorse/client/net_http/handler.rb:60:in `transmit'
/Users/kross/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@acme/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.1.26/lib/seahorse/client/net_http/handler.rb:34:in `call'
/Users/kross/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@acme/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.1.26/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/content_length.rb:12:in `call'
/Users/kross/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@acme/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.1.26/lib/aws-sdk-core/xml/error_handler.rb:8:in `call'
/Users/kross/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@acme/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.1.26/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/request_signer.rb:85:in `call'
/Users/kross/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@acme/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.1.26/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/retry_errors.rb:87:in `call'
/Users/kross/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@acme/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.1.26/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/retry_errors.rb:118:in `retry_request'
/Users/kross/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@acme/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.1.26/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/retry_errors.rb:101:in `retry_if_possible'
/Users/kross/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@acme/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.1.26/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/retry_errors.rb:89:in `call'
/Users/kross/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@acme/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.1.26/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/retry_errors.rb:118:in `retry_request'
/Users/kross/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@acme/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.1.26/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/retry_errors.rb:101:in `retry_if_possible'
/Users/kross/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@acme/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.1.26/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/retry_errors.rb:89:in `call'
/Users/kross/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@acme/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.1.26/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/retry_errors.rb:118:in `retry_request'
/Users/kross/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@acme/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.1.26/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/retry_errors.rb:101:in `retry_if_possible'
/Users/kross/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@acme/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.1.26/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/retry_errors.rb:89:in `call'
/Users/kross/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@acme/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.1.26/lib/aws-sdk-core/query/handler.rb:27:in `call'
/Users/kross/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@acme/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.1.26/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/user_agent.rb:12:in `call'
/Users/kross/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@acme/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.1.26/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/endpoint.rb:34:in `call'
/Users/kross/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@acme/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.1.26/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/param_validator.rb:21:in `call'
/Users/kross/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@acme/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.1.26/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/raise_response_errors.rb:14:in `call'
/Users/kross/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@acme/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.1.26/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/param_converter.rb:21:in `call'
/Users/kross/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@acme/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.1.26/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/response_paging.rb:26:in `call'
/Users/kross/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@acme/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.1.26/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/response_target.rb:21:in `call'
/Users/kross/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@acme/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.1.26/lib/seahorse/client/request.rb:70:in `send_request'
/Users/kross/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@acme/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.1.26/lib/seahorse/client/base.rb:207:in `block (2 levels) in define_operation_methods'
/Users/kross/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@acme/gems/eb_deployer-0.6.3/lib/eb_deployer/aws_driver/beanstalk.rb:20:in `application_exists?'
/Users/kross/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@acme/gems/eb_deployer-0.6.3/lib/eb_deployer/throttling_handling.rb:13:in `block in method_missing'
/Users/kross/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@acme/gems/eb_deployer-0.6.3/lib/eb_deployer/utils.rb:13:in `backoff'
/Users/kross/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@acme/gems/eb_deployer-0.6.3/lib/eb_deployer/throttling_handling.rb:12:in `method_missing'
/Users/kross/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@acme/gems/eb_deployer-0.6.3/lib/eb_deployer/application.rb:86:in `create_application_if_not_exists'
/Users/kross/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@acme/gems/eb_deployer-0.6.3/lib/eb_deployer/application.rb:15:in `create_version'
/Users/kross/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@acme/gems/eb_deployer-0.6.3/lib/eb_deployer.rb:218:in `deploy'
```

Question: is anyone else having a problem making sure AWS is utilizing the reserved instance? Is there a configuration trick I'm missing?

Comment: [Placing beanstalk in specific availability zone](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=266223&#266223)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This forum post has details on zones for instances: [Placing beanstalk in specific availability zone](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=266223&#266223).  *Availability Zones* are note the same as *Regions*, therein lies my misunderstanding.

For example, this keeps it to one specific zone:

```
[
  { "Namespace":"aws:autoscaling:asg",
    "OptionName":"Custom Availability Zones",
    "Value":"us-east-1c" },
  { "Namespace":"aws:autoscaling:asg",
    "OptionName":"Availability Zones",
    "Value":"Any 1" }
]
```

For [elastic-beanstalk gem](https://github.com/alienfast/elastic-beanstalk), I alter the options in my `eb.yml`:

```
region: us-east-1
options:
  aws:autoscaling:asg:
    'Custom Availability Zones': us-east-1c
    'Availability Zones': Any 1
```

For multiple AZs, this could be something like:

```
region: us-east-1
options:
  aws:autoscaling:asg:
    'Custom Availability Zones': 'us-east-1c, us-east-1d'
    'Availability Zones': Any 2
```

Comment: Additionally if you are in a VPC you will need to set the "Subnets" option in the "aws:ec2:vpc" namespace: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html